# How to align cards in hand in a circular way?

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, card-game

I am working on a card game in Unity, and by now I instantiated my cards on a canvas. Now I would like to align them like I am holding them in real life.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite[] Cards;
    public GameObject CardPrefab;
    public static string[] TypeOfCard = { "tref", "herc", "pik", "kara" };
    public static string[] ValueOfCard = { "_sedam", "_osam", "_devet", "_deset", "_decko", "_baba", "_kralj", "_as" };
    public List<string> Deck;
    public GameObject CardDeck;
    public GameObject Player1;
    public GameObject Player2;
    public GameObject Player3;
    public GameObject Player4;
   

    public List<string> Player1Hand;
    public List<string> Player2Hand;
    public List<string> Player3Hand;
    public List<string> Player4Hand;
    void Start()
    {
        GameStart();
    }

    public void GameStart()
    {
        CreatingDeck();
        Deck = CreatingDeck();
        Shuffle(Deck);
        DeckOfCards();
        CardSpawn();
       
    }
    public static List<string> CreatingDeck()
    {
        List<string> newdeck = new List<string>();
        foreach (string x in TypeOfCard)
        {
            foreach(string y in ValueOfCard)
            {
                newdeck.Add(x + y);
            }
        }
        return newdeck;
    }

    void Shuffle<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        System.Random random = new System.Random();
        int n = list.Count;

        while(n>1)
        {
            int k = random.Next(n);
            n--;

            T temp = list[k];
            list[k] = list[n];
            list[n] = temp;
        }
    }
    private static System.Random rng = new System.Random();
    public static void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> list)
    {
        int n = list.Count;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
            T value = list[k];
            list[k] = list[n];
            list[n] = value;
        }
    }
    void DeckOfCards()
    {
        
        foreach (string CardName in Deck)
        {
            GameObject cards = Instantiate(CardPrefab, CardDeck.transform);
            cards.name = CardName;
        }
       
    }
    
    void CardSpawn()
    {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            Player1Hand.Add(CardDeck.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.name);
        }
        Player1Hand.Sort();
        foreach (var cardname in Player1Hand)
        {
            CardDeck.transform.Find(cardname).gameObject.transform.SetParent(Player1.transform);
            Player1.transform.Find(cardname).gameObject.GetComponent<CardInfo>().IsFaceOn = true;


            Player1.transform.Find(cardname).gameObject.transform.position = newPos;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            Player2Hand.Add(CardDeck.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.name);
        }
        Player2Hand.Sort();
        foreach (var cardname in Player2Hand)
        {
            CardDeck.transform.Find(cardname).gameObject.transform.SetParent(Player2.transform);
            Player2.transform.Find(cardname).gameObject.GetComponent<CardInfo>().IsFaceOn = true;
            Player2.transform.Find(cardname).gameObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward*90);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            Player3Hand.Add(CardDeck.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.name);
        }
        Player3Hand.Sort();
        foreach (var cardname in Player3Hand)
        {
            CardDeck.transform.Find(cardname).gameObject.transform.SetParent(Player3.transform);
            Player3.transform.Find(cardname).gameObject.GetComponent<CardInfo>().IsFaceOn = true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            Player4Hand.Add(CardDeck.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.name);
        }
        Player4Hand.Sort();
        foreach (var cardname in Player4Hand)
        {
            CardDeck.transform.Find(cardname).gameObject.transform.SetParent(Player4.transform);
            Player4.transform.Find(cardname).gameObject.GetComponent<CardInfo>().IsFaceOn = true;
            Player4.transform.Find(cardname).gameObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * 270);
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: You mean holding them in an arc? You could define a point below your hand and have each card rotated towards that point. The further the point is away, the more straight your cards are going to be. Together with a since wave it should make a realistic card holding. (just leaving a comment since I'm not at my pc for an example code)

Comment: You can probably find the answer using the formula for a circle and remapping the position into your canvas, but if you want to take the lazy way. You could create a temporary game object (let's call it player hand) then parent your cards to it one at a time, and rotate the hand by something like 90/Player1Hand.Count each time. That should evenly space your cards out in a 90 degree angle.